# Using Python's tk_tools.py led

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with the led option 'on_click_callback=' of the led widget in the module tk_tools.py. Here's what I have:

```
reactor_led = Led(win, size=50, toggle_on_click=True,       on_click_callback=led_clicked(ON))
reactor_led.to_red()
reactor_led.to_green(on=True)
reactor_led.grid()
```

The led does get displayed properly in its window, and it does react correctly to a mouse click. I've omitted the code for led_clicked, but it is being called when I click the 'led'. The parameter "ON" is the boolean state of the led when clicked, but I can't come up with the actual code to reference that to pass to the call-back function. I need a working example to understand it.
Thanks

Comment: The callback function receives the state as a parameter, automatically.  You'd just write `on_click_callback=led_clicked` (with no parentheses) when creating the Led - the way you've currently written it, *you're* calling the function one time, and using its return value (probably None) as the actual callback.

Comment: You're right, Jason. Thanks. I set the callback as 'def led_clicked(state: bool):', and that gave me access to the led's state.